# creating a playlist from listbox selection and playing it using VLC?

Tags: wxpython, vlc

Need some hints/help in a stupid little problem.

I have a list of files in a listbox. I want to get a selection of files from the list, add them in a playlist and play it using VLC. But I dont know how to start that bit.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Mohsin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Python's subprocess module and pass the names of the files to play on the command line:

http://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/vlc/2006-January/012703.html

That link shows how to do it with movies, but I suspect music works the same way.

If you're using wxPython, you'll want to put this in an event handler:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("path/to/vla.exe mp3_1 mp3_2")
```

If you want to create a playlist, it would appear that VLC uses a XML-like format:

http://wiki.videolan.org/XSPF

I would use Python's XML libraries to create the XML. I prefer the 3rd party [lxml](http://lxml.de/) one.

Comment: Thanks for the information Mike. I am using Python as a programming language. So if you can point me in right direction, that would be great.